# DRF expose model field in two separate read-write fields on the REST API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm using Python 2.7, DRF 3.1.3, Django 1.4.21 (I know it's old but it's a large codebase, one day we'll migrate). The real-world business case is more complicated than this, here is the simplified version.

I have a model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

On the REST API I want to expose two fields, both of them is derived from foo. Both fields should be writable, and both fields would set the foo field in a way when I write into it.
Try 1: bar is unfortunately read-only

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')

    def get_bar(self, obj):
        return get_bar(obj.foo) # not relevant now what get_bar does
```

Try 2: trying to fake a field somehow

```
class PlaceholderCharField(serializers.CharField):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        pass

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        pass

class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    bar = PlaceholderCharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super(PersonSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
        data['bar'] = get_bar(instance.foo)
        return data

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        instance = super(PersonSerializer, self).to_internal_value(data)
        if data.has_key('bar') and not data.has_key('foo'):
            instance.foo = get_foo(data['bar']) if data['bar'] else None
        return instance
```

This latter one errors out obviously complaining that the `Person` model doesn't have a bar field. Which is true. How to solve this problem? I can handle setting/getting the foo and bar in the serializer's `to_representation` and `to_internal_value`. I just want a way in `DRF` to specify a field, which only exists on the `REST API` side, and doesn't have a field associated on the model end. I can take care of the transformations. And that field should be read-write, otherwise I could just solve it with a `SerializerMethodField`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tweak your first attempt a little and you can alias that field, no problem:

```
class PersonSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #                 vvvvvvvvv
    bar = serializers.CharField(
       source='foo', required=False
    )# ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')
```

I'm still using DRF 2.4.4 for the better nested, multi-object nested serializer support, but I use that method for aliasing a URL and its associate object all the time to deal with the way Angular JS compares objects in some of its controls.  e.g.

```
class SensorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    location_obj = SensorLocationSerializer(source='location',read_only=True,required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'name', 'serial_number', 'location', 
            'location_obj', 'active')
```

Comment: But how will the 'bar' be writable if I mark it explicitly read_only? That looks like the same as if I had a SerializerMethodField(). In my case the two pairs of fields I came across so far with this problem are not RelatedFields or RelaterPrimaryKeyFields (thank God).

Comment: Edited.   How about this form, without the `read_only` flag?  It should still alias it.  The only conflict will come from having both `foo` and `bar` in an update.  I'm not sure which would win..   it will probably be the last field listed in your `Meta.fields`.  I think you'll still have aliasing issues, regardless, because you're fundamentally aliasing a field.  You could write an explicit serializer and view for only this backwards compatible chap.

Comment: Oh, so I can just simply have two fields in the same serializer which refer to the same source field?

Comment: Yes.  You can do that.  Beware the data race.

Answer (score 2):

I'm unsure of your usecase, it seems a little odd, but why don't you just add a property on your **model**. For example,

```
   @property
    def bar(self):
        """
        Used for DRF only.
        """
        return None # or self.foo
```

Then add it to your fields in the serializer (no need to use `PlaceholderCharField`)

```
fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')
```

The rest will work as you have it.

Comment: I was thinking about that. Is there a way to add a field to the Model so it won't cause a schema change, won't get persisted?

Comment: I admit that my use-case is weird. Everything is inherited from earlier non REST APIs, and the client developer's time is more precious than mine.

Comment: If you add the property above to your model it won't be persisted to the DB and won't require migrations.